# Eclipse Juno/Android broken, the debug is wrong and gen folder not created (R error)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a very very strange issue, and i believe my elcipse juno is broken. I have the Android ADT plugin in this eclipse.

The following screenshot will prove my believe.

[image]

And its not finished yet. After the screenshot above, i press F6 again, and this is what i got :

[image]

I will explain this case once again to make a clear question. I debug my application, then i got that the `arg2` value is 1. After that, i press f6 and the code goes to case 0 (instead of case 1) and then i press f6 again and the code goes to case 6 (WTF????? i do have a `break`, how come it comes to case 0 and case 6?)

In case you need it, this is the code in the above screenshots :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Chapter.class);

        switch(arg2)
        {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            i.putExtra("key", 1);
            Toast.makeText(this, arg2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 2:
            i.putExtra("key", 2);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 3:
            i.putExtra("key", 3);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 4:
            i.putExtra("key", 4);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 5:
            i.putExtra("key", 5);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 6:
            i.putExtra("key", 6);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 7:
            i.putExtra("key", 7);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 8:
            i.putExtra("key", 8);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion use activity context Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Chapter.class); Use activity context for displaying toast also

Comment: Quick test project on my Juno (ADT Plugin only) shows totally correct behavior of debugger. Do you try to clean your project? (probably yes but it's better to clarify)

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for your suggestion. It has no effect :D

Comment: @IdanAdar Unfortunately, i cant remove worklight because i will need it shortly

Comment: @Vyacheslav not yet (for the latest version of code),i will let you know after i tried it.

Comment: @Vyacheslav talking about cleaning project, i have a weird experience the last time i clean THIS project. Theres no error before cleaning, however the eclipse give me "R" error after cleaning. This is a very common error and i have faced it many times, but this time the error is UNFIXABLE (i have tried all i know), so i decided to copy a fresh project from my backup. Do you think its related?

Comment: @BlazeTama think no - missing R.java it's really common problem and there are at least two reasons why it happens: 1) Error somewhere in *.xml file (lint can help to found it) 2) Import android.R instead yourproject.R. Also if you have updated Android SDK to version 22 check that Android BuildTools installed.

Comment: @Vyacheslav just want to inform you that its because a bug in the ADT 22, please see my answer. Thanks very much for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES**, it is broken because of the bug in **ADT 22**. I need to upgrade the ADT to latest version and install **Android Build Tools**. After that, the program and the debugging runs NORMALLY.

Those are the links that may help you if you encounter a same problem with me :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/rCaeT3qckoE
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/epOfZbKPFdk

Answer (score 1):

I could be completely wrong, but this seems normal to me. The cases work like arrays where the first instance is 0 where your `arg2` is an int so the first instance is 1

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, arg2 is an int, not an array. And what should i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Yeah I said arg2 is an int. The cases work like an array. Is your program actually throwing an error or are you just not getting the result you want?

Comment: You might just have to change your code a little then (based on the parts you provided). But everything looks ok to me

Comment: Thanks for your help. No need to change the code, it was a bug in ADT 22. Please see my answer. Thanks :D