# Could not find apk with ibm worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

This is my first time learning IBM Worklight, so please bear with me. I was following [this](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/02_03_Previewing_your_application_on_Android.pdf) tutorial, however i stucked in **page 14**, where the tutorial tell me to "**run as android project**" so the project will be run on android simulator.

This is the error i got :

```
Could not find HelloWorklightHelloWorklightAndroid.apk!
```

What should i do? I also have watched [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnjTfZpSKNo) video, and everything works fine in that video (no error like mine)

Thanks for your time, any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Downvoting my question?why?at least leave a comment so i can prove my question

Comment: @dtmilano i'm a student and IBM give it to me for free because i join their competition. However i will try to post this problem in their forum :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is because a **BUG** in **ADT 22**.  I need to upgrade the ADT to latest version and install **Android Build Tools**.

The way to solve this bug (and get things working )is in my another question (which share the same problem, because i use a same android sdk) :

[Eclipse Juno/Android broken, the debug is wrong and gen folder not created (R error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883655/eclipse-juno-android-broken-the-debug-is-wrong-and-gen-folder-not-created-r-er)

**EDIT**

After that, you probably will get `CLASSNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION` because (again) **ADT 22**, so you need to do (a little) more things in this [IBM link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM89348)

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug in ADT 22 as much as the fact you need to install Android Build Tools.  Since Android Build Tools doesn't show up until after you've installed the latest SDK, it's easy to miss this step.  One way for others to check if this is the problem is to use the Android tools to export an APK directly - if so, they will see a missing build tools error message.

Comment: @NellGawor Thanks for your additional information. I suddenly got this error after i update my ADT to 22.0.0 :D

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project and build it again it works.

Comment: Delete the android project.Build and deploy once again.

Comment: i was using Juno with ADT 22 but never faced such problem maybe it was upto date i guess :D anyway Thanks for informing :)